# C# Thread.Run inside For loop what is the behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, operating-system, task, task-parallel-library

I making an Experiment, I have a loop of 100000 increments and inside it there is a thread that does a specific task(write a log to DB), my question is when I run it its finish in one second maybe and it start to insert them lately,  then how the OS handles them and it will process them all or will skip from them?
I try awaited method with them its good. but I want to know what will happen if this code was on a server and received 100000 requests.
The Code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Task.Run(() => log.WriteToLog(i + "", new Models.CustomerModel.CustomerModel()));

        }
```

I am not looking for alternative ways, I need to know the behaviour and how this code handles in OS (if there is a queue, some of them will run, etc..)

PS: I know its not a good approach

Comment: It’s a really bad idea to start 100.000 tasks at the same time. It could theoretically start the same amount of threads which is a huge resource consumption and could grind the system to virtually a stop. You don’t await tasks, which can be fine, but you need to think what should happen when the can’t be written. In this case up to 100.000 exceptions may be posted to the task scheduler as unobserved exceptions, so the user could be shown this amount of error messages.

Comment: Also the tasks may be processed and proceed in an arbitrary order so your log is all over the place. A better idea would be to have a dedicated logging task and push the log messages into this task to be processed. For this use-case where the producer (providing a log entry) and consumer (outputting the entry) operate on different speeds and there may be many producers, you should use a producer consumer pattern see the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I know its bad, but the idea is to know what will happen and if they will go to queue to compare it with the thread pool method.

Comment: Tasks use the ThreadPool so this is a slightly better approach. It will probably work and create some extra threads but not prohibitively.

Comment: @ckuri - the threadpool and the Task scheduler will limit this. It's not a great approach but you won't get 1000s of threads either.

Comment: @bommelding Thanks, I suspected something like this, but I still think one shouldn't rely on such implicit implementing details. And even if it's only a (few) dozen threads it's still a bad idea  as to let logging take all available threads from the pool. I guess we can agree that having only one dedicated logging thread avoids many pitfalls without much of performance penalty or even improved performance as one doesn't need to sync between different logging threads.

Comment: A few dozen would be a disaster on a server, negligible on a client desktop. But the I/O might still be killing it. It all depends. So yes, use a standard logging library.

Comment: The question might be interesting, but as it is written it's too broad. While the current answer and the comments give some useful information and insight, the behavior (that is, the answer to the question) will depend on the machine and some other missing context information.

Comment: @pac0 yes I did not write the question in a proper way, exactly I meant the behavior, not alternative solutions. Thanks for your Intervention

Answer (score 2):

1 second is a bit quick.  I suspect you are **not** logging 100000 entries properly and entries are being **lost**.

Assuming that code was the only code inside say a console app's `main()`, then because you don't `await` any of the tasks, it is entirely possible your process is exiting before the logging is complete.

Change:

```
Task.Run(() => log.WriteToLog(i + "", 
                              new Models.CustomerModel.CustomerModel()));
```

...to:

```
await Task.Run(() => log.WriteToLog(i + "", 
                                    new Models.CustomerModel.CustomerModel()));
```

Also, as ckuri mentions in the comments, spawning a great deal of tasks in a tight loop probably isn't a good idea.  Consider batching the logging or using IOCP.

Comment: i don't want to wait for the task to finish, its a log.
i wondering what happened after I run the code . and what is the best practice.

Comment: @MohdLom I don't believe your code is logging 100000 entries.  Don't equate `await` as _synchronous wait, blocking the current thread until the task is finished before moving onto the next task_

Comment: @MickyD, but it will not enqueue the next task until the first Task.Run is awaited, no?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü No.  Tasks are created immediately with `Task.Run`.  By not prefixing it with `await` you are creating a _fire-and-forget-task_.   Generally this is ok (but it can be problematic with exception handling). However, you need to ensure your process does not exit prematurely.

Comment: On the other hand, I wanted to ask about prefixed by `await`. In the case of `await Task.Run(() => log.WriteToLog(i + "", 
                                    new Models.CustomerModel.CustomerModel()));` They will all run one by one right?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü They will each run a task at a time but with possible concurrency